# How to create a multi label classification network in Keras if I have the training data with various accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a neural network that finds the most effective treatment for each patient.

I have a medical database for training. The **inputs** are histological and pathological data (mostly 0/1 data of having some diseases, conditions) and the **outputs** are the treatments. And there is an **accuracy** score, which is the patient's reaction to the treatment (this shows how good was the treatment for the symptoms, so how accurate was the input-output pair).

How can I create a multi label classification network that finds the best treatment if **the training data pairs are not always totally correct**, rather having these variable accuracy scores?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a dummy class that represents **no treatment** and use the accuracy score via a threshold (lower than threshold) correspond to no treatment at all.

Threshold as used above becomes a new hyper-parameter and you have new input-output pairs that are now exact (depending on threshold).